# Const keyword problem if we make the [1,2] constant then geek1 == geek2 will print true otherwise false how?

Tags: dart

I am trying to understand the const keyword I found an article on GeeksforGeeks of const but I didn't understand it if we make the [1,2] constant then geek1 == geek2 will print true otherwise false how?

```
// Declaring a function
gfg() =>[1, 2]; // if we write here gfg() => const [1, 2]; then geek1 == geek2 will print true

// Main function
void main() {
// Assiging value
// through function
  var geek1 = gfg();
  var geek2 = gfg();

// Printing result
// true
  print(geek1 == geek2);
  print(geek1);
  print(geek2);
}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const

Answer (score 1):

1. `==` for arrays in dart compares references. Meaning that two arrays, although with identical contents can return `false` on comparison with `==`.
2. `const` defines a compile-time constant, but it would also work with a class attribute. It's just important, that instead of creating a new array, the function returns the same reference twice.

The difference between the two functions is essentially, that in the first one, you define a new array with each call of the function (different reference each time), while in the second one you define a compile-time constant, that is returned on each call of the function (same reference each time).

So let's see some examples:

```dart
class Factory {
  List<int> arr = [1, 2];
  final finalArr = [1, 2];
  static const constArr = [1, 2];

  getValue() => [1, 2];
  getInlineConst() => const [1, 2];
  getRef() => arr;
  getFinalRef() => finalArr;
  getConstRef() => constArr;
}

void main() {
  final f = new Factory();
  print("values: ${f.getValue() == f.getValue()}");
  print("const inline:  ${f.getInlineConst() == f.getInlineConst()}");
  print("reference: ${f.getRef() == f.getRef()}");
  print("final reference: ${f.getFinalRef() == f.getFinalRef()}");
  print("const reference:  ${f.getConstRef() == f.getConstRef()}");

  final refBefore = f.getRef();
  f.arr = [1, 2];
  final refAfter = f.getRef();
  print("reference (with change inbetween): ${refBefore == refAfter}");
}
```

Output is:

```
values: false
const inline:  true
reference: true
final reference: true
const reference:  true
reference (with change inbetween): false
```

Comment: `final` is completely irrelevant. `getReference` just needs to return the same object; whether `arr` is declared `final` or not makes no difference.  The discussion of `final` in this answer is misleading.

Comment: im not discussing final in this answer, im explicitly stating, that its just important to return the same reference twice. im giving an example, that this is also possible with final instead of const, since the question explicitly asked about the const keyword .... it would also be possible with a non-final, non-const class attribute, given, that the reference does not change between function calls (basically would need to be pseudo final) ...

Comment: But your use of `final` in your answer is misleading since a reader could misinterpret it to mean that `final` is related to the behavior.  You should just remove all references to `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Dart canonicalizes constants. That means that `const Foo(1)` in one part of the program evaluates to the *same object* as `const Foo(1)` in another part of the program. There is only one object. That extends to constant lists too: `const [1, 2, 3]` will evaluate to the *same* constant list everywhere it occurs in the program.

Non-constant object creation creates a new object each time its evaluated: `Foo(1)` or `new Foo(1)` will create a new object each time. Same for list iterals.

So, `identical(const [1, 2, 3], const [1, 2, 3])` is true, but `identical([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])` is false.

The `==` of Dart's built-in lists does not compare the contents of the list. It's inherited from `Object` and only checks whether it's the same object (basically using `bool operator==(Object other) => identical(this, other);`).